# GNU parallel with custom script doing string comparison

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, string-comparison, large-files

The follwoing `script.sh` compares part of a string (coming from `stdin` by `cat`ing a csv file) to a defined string and reports the differences in a certain format

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

reference="ABCDEFG"
ref_transp=$(echo "$reference" | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
while read line; do
  line_transp=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f2 | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
  output=$(paste -d ' ' <(echo "$ref_transp") <(echo "$line_transp") | grep -vnP '([A-Z]) \1' | sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9]*):([A-Z]) ([A-Z]*)/\2\1\3/' | grep '^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*[A-Z*]$')
  echo "$(echo ${line:0:35}, $output)"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

It is intendet to be executed on a number of rows from a very large file in the format

```
XYZ,ABMDEFG
```

and it works well when i use it in a pipe:

```
cat large_file | ./find_something.sh
```

However, when I try to use it with `parallel`, i get this error:

```
$  cat large_file | parallel ./find_something.sh
./find_something.sh: line 9: XYZ, ABMDEFG : No such file or directory
```

What is causing this? Is `parallel` supposed to work for something like this, if I want to redirect the output to a single file afterwards?

Less important side note: I'm rather proud of my string comparison method, but if someone has a faster way to get from comparing `ABCDEFG` and `XYZ,ABMDEFG` to obtain `XYZ,C3M` I'd be happy to hear that, too.

### Edit:

I should have said, I also want to preserve the order of each line in the output, corresponding to the input. Is that possible using parallel?

Comment: please edit your Q to show the required output from your sample input. ALSO please include sample data for `reference` and any other static data you're using. Good luck.

Comment: Consider running your script with 'set -x' at the top. You will get information that will help you debug the problem. Also, please post the line with the XYZ, ABMDEFG (and some other good lines), so it will be possible to replicate

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are running about 10 external processes for every line, `cut`, `sed`, `grep`, `paste` and so on. Presumably you want to use GNU Parallel to speed this up. I can't help thinking you would do much better to show input and desired output and do the whole lot in one `awk` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script accepts its input from a file (defaulting to stdin), whereas `parallel` will pass input as arguments, not via stdin. In that sense, `parallel` is closer to `xargs`.

Presumably, you want each of the lines in `large_file` to be processed as a unit, possibly in parallel.

That means you need your script to only process one such line at a time, and let `parallel` call your script many times, once for each line.

So your script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

reference="ABCDEFG"
ref_transp=$(echo "$reference" | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
line="$1"
line_transp=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f2 | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
output=$(paste -d ' ' <(echo "$ref_transp") <(echo "$line_transp") | grep -vnP '([A-Z]) \1' | sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9]*):([A-Z]) ([A-Z]*)/\2\1\3/' | grep '^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*[A-Z*]$')
echo "$(echo ${line:0:35}, $output)"
```

Then you can redirect to a file as follows:

```
cat large_file | parallel ./find_something.sh > output_file
```

Comment: This is the correct solution to my original question. However, it messes up the order of lines. Any way to prevent this or is this an icompatible desire with parallel?

Comment: if you run things in parallel, you lose the order. if you need to preserve the order, I propose something like `cat -n large_file | parallel ./find_something.sh | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-` and have `find_something.sh` just write the first argument as it is followed by a space and then the actual output. To see how it works, imagine that `find_something.sh` is just `tac | xargs -L 1 echo`, and run e.g. `cat -n /etc/passwd | tac | xargs -L 1 echo | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Answer (score 1):

`-k` keeps the order.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doit() {    
    reference="ABCDEFG"
    ref_transp=$(echo "$reference" | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
    while read line; do
      line_transp=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f2 | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
      output=$(paste -d ' ' <(echo "$ref_transp") <(echo "$line_transp") | grep -vnP '([A-Z]) \1' | sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9]*):([A-Z]) ([A-Z]*)/\2\1\3/' | grep '^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*[A-Z*]$')
      echo "$(echo ${line:0:35}, $output)"
    done
}
export -f doit

cat large_file | parallel --pipe -k doit
#or
parallel --pipepart -a large_file --block -10 -k doit
```

Comment: Somehow it gives me empty strings in this way, but thanks for pointing me to the --pipe option, that seems to work too

Comment: I have tested it on large_file containing: `XYZ,ABMDEFG` and it gives the same output, so I am puzzled why you get empty strings. Keeping the order the same as input is easy: Use `-k`.